# Django Redis cache get TTL (expire time)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, redis, django-cache, django-redis

Is it possible to get key's expire time in Django using Redis cache?
Something like:

```
from django.core.cache import cache  

cache.get_expire('mykey')  # 300 (seconds)
```

I tried:

```
cache.ttl('my_key')
```

getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'RedisCache' object has no attribute 'ttl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official API to get [**`TTL`**](https://redis.io/commands/ttl/) from [**`RedisCache`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#redis) backend in Django (as of `Django 4.2`); but we can customize the backend like -

```py
# somefile.py

from functools import cached_property

from django.core.cache.backends.redis import (
    RedisCache as _RedisCache,
    RedisCacheClient as _RedisCacheClient,
)


class RedisCacheClient(_RedisCacheClient):
    def ttl(self, key):
        client = self.get_client(key)
        return client.ttl(key)


class RedisCache(_RedisCache):
    @cached_property
    def _cache(self):
        return RedisCacheClient(self._servers, **self._options)

    def ttl(self, key, version=None):
        key = self.make_and_validate_key(key, version=version)
        return self._cache.ttl(key)
```

and then update your `settings.py`

```
# settings.py

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "path.to.new.custom.backend.RedisCache",
        # other parameters and options
    },
}
```

#### Results

```
In [1]: from django.core.cache import cache

In [2]: cache.get("test")

In [3]: cache.set("test", "Foo", 30)

In [4]: cache.get("test")
Out[4]: 'Foo'

In [5]: cache.ttl("test")
Out[5]: 21

In [6]: cache.ttl("test")
Out[6]: 19

In [7]: cache.ttl("any-key")
Out[7]: -2
```